# How to make Thread.callstacksymbols output readable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dwarf, symbolicate

I used Thread.callStackSymbol to get stack trace but it's not readable.
I saw several StackOverflow answers but none of them is working. Following is the process I followed to make stack trace readable

Sample stack trace :
**[
0: "projectName", "hex code(stack address)", "less readable method name + number(offset)",
1: "projectName", "hex code(stack address)", "less readable method name + number(offset)",
]**

1. In one StackOverflow answer I read that I need to calculate load address first using formula **load address = stackaddress - offset** and then use **atos -o path to dSYM file -l loadaddress stackaddress**
   It's giving output like **"some hex code(in projectName)"** but not giving proper location and line number in my code
2. In another stackoverflow article I read we can use command **dwardump --lookup symbolic address --arch architecture dSYM_file_location** and symbolic address can be calculated using **slide + stack address - load address** where we can get **slide and load address using "_dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(0)" and "_dyld_get_image_header(0)"**. This command is not giving any output in terminal

I also checked the uuid of my dSYM file and my app both are the same and the file is also not corrupted.
I need help on how can I make it readable.

I a using xcode 12 to build my application and I am getting the location of my dSYM file from the **Show the report navigation** section of xcode.

**Currently I am trying this in my simulator devices** and launching my application using **launch button present at the top left of xcode** and logging stack trace in debugger (print(Thread.callstacksymbol))

**How can I make stack trace readable/what I am missing**

Comment: I suggest to take a look at this excellent WWDC 2021 video dealing with symbolication ⟹ https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10211/ 